# Erro em classxml

Tags: php

Alguém poderia mim falar como resolver este erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo acessarserver.php:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("server.php?id=8");
echo $xml;
```

Arquivo server.php:

```
<?php 
include("classxml.php");

$xml = new Xml();

$erro = 0;

$idproduto = $_GET['id'];

$xml->openTag('response');

if($idproduto=='') {

    $erro = '1';
    $msg  = 'codigo invalido!';
} else {

    $erro = '2';
    $msg  = 'codigo valido!';
}
$xml->addTag('erro',$erro);
$xml->addTag('msg',$msg);
$xml->closeTag('response');

echo $xml;
```

Arquivo classxml.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of XmlClass
 *
 * @author Rafael
 */
class Xml {

    private $xml;
    private $tab = 1;
    public function __construct($version="1.0", $encoding="UTF-8") {
        $this->xml .= "<?xml version='$version' encoding='$encoding'?>\n";
    }

    public function openTag($name){
        $this->addTab();
        $this->xml .= "<$name>\n";
        $this->tab++;
    }

    public function closeTag($name){
        $this->tab--;
        $this->addTab();
        $this->xml .= "</$name>\n";        
    }

    public function addTag($name, $value){
        $this->addTab();
        $this->xml .= "<$name>$value</$name>\n";
    }

    private function addTab(){
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->tab; $i++){
            $this->xml .= "\t";
        }
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->xml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu arquivo XML está inválido, ou seja, ele está com erro de sintaxe.
Para conferir se o arquivo está válido ou não, passe ele em um validador de XML como este http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: O erro é no inicio da classe. Mas já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei a solução. ERRO(Content is not allowed in prolog) help galera!

Comment: Você pelo menos passou o arquivo no validador? Salvar o XML em arquivo e valide se o formato gerado pela classe está correto.

Comment: Outra coisa: no arquivo server.php tem um erro, vc tem q informar q o retorno é XML colocando o seguinte código na primeira linha do server.php:
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

Comment: Passei filipe. O erro(Content is not allowed in prolog) foi nessa linha: $this->xml .= "<?xml version='$version' encoding='$encoding'?>\n";. passei em outro validador e o erro foi este:Erro no processamento de XML: formatação incorreta
Número da linha 7, coluna 71:
$this->xml .="<?xml version='$version' encoding='$encoding' ?>\n";